# How to execute a ConnectAll Application restart script using a cron Job

Tags: 18.04, scripts, cron

Could you please guide me with the following,

Adding the ConnectAll Application restart script for reference:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
# JIRA startup script
#chkconfig: 2345 80 05
#description: JIRA

# Define some variables
# Name of app ( JIRA, Confluence, etc )
APP=connectall
APP1=Mule
# Name of the user to run as
USER=root
# Location of application's bin directory
BASE=/mulesoft/connectall/CATomcat/bin
#BASEMule=/mulesoft/connectall/mulesoft/mule-standalone-3.9.0
# Location of Java JDK
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk1.8.0_171


case "$1" in

 # Stop command
  stop)
    #echo "Stopping $APP"
    #/bin/su -m $USER -c "$BASE/shutdown.sh &> /dev/null"
    #echo "$APP stopped successfully"


    echo "Stopping $APP1"
    /bin/su -m $USER -c "/mulesoft/connectall/mulesoft/mule-standalone-3.9.0/bin/mule stop &> /dev/null"
    echo "$APP1 stopped successfully"

    echo "Stopping $APP"
    /bin/su -m $USER -c "$BASE/shutdown.sh &> /dev/null"
    echo "$APP stopped successfully"
    ;;

  # Start command
  start)
    echo "Starting $APP"
    /bin/su -m $USER -c "$BASE/startup.sh &> /dev/null"
    echo "$APP started successfully"

     echo "Starting $APP1"
    /bin/su -m $USER -c "/mulesoft/connectall/mulesoft/mule-standalone-3.9.0/bin/mule start &> /dev/null"
    echo "$APP1 started successfully"

    ;;
  # Stop command
 # stop)
  #  echo "Stopping $APP"
   # /bin/su -m $USER -c "$BASE/bin/shutdown.sh &> /dev/null"
    #echo "$APP stopped successfully"
    #;;
   #Restart command
   restart)
        $0 stop
        sleep 60
        $0 start
        ;;
  *)
 echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/$APP restart}"
  exit 1
   ;;
esac
```

The above script is in the name connectall-auto-restart in the location /mulesoft (this is an external mount).
So when I execute the script manually from the location /mulesoft using ./connectall-auto-restart restart  the application restarts fine.

However when I configure the same in a cron job like below

```
30 08 1-7 * 6 /mulesoft/connectall-auto-restart
30 08 17-23 * 6 /mulesoft/connectall-auto-restart
```

the cron runs exactly at the time but the cron does not initiate the script. (Meaning the cron triggers the job but my application is not restarting).

```
root@balqmu101:/var/log# cat syslog | grep connectall-auto-restart
Sep 18 08:30:01 balqmu101 CRON[3232401]: (root) CMD (/mulesoft/connectall-auto-restart)
```

I have also tried the following and that also is not working.

```
30 08 1-7 * 6 /mulesoft/connectall-auto-restart restart
30 08 17-23 * 6 /mulesoft/connectall-auto-restart restart
```

Regards
Aravind Viswanathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jobs run through `cron`, or `systemd` startup scripts aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. `systemd` startup scripts are run as `root`. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings from `~/.bashrc` are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== id ===";id;echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.

Since the `command` part of the `crontab` line is, by default,  interpreted by `/bin/sh`, which has a simpler syntax than `/bin/bash`, I recommend having `command` be a call to a `bash` script  (executable, mounted, starts with `#!/bin/bash`) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.

Comment: Hi Waltinator, You are a Genius. Yes your suggestion worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please click the checkmark to "accept" my answer, if it helped you, and might help others.

Comment: where is the "accept" on this screen?

Comment: Click the checkmark.